# execute shell script from ruby on rails with passing variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, shell, shell-exec

Im trying to integrate prosody xmpp server with my rails application. I need to create some users in a database upon registration so I can lateron use them inside the prosody server.

What would be the best way to run shell commands in rails and output any info logs ?

```
prosodyctl adduser User.username
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i usually run with `system(command)`,or with backtick `command`,other way you can refer [here](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)