# Can I setup different SSL certificates sub-domain wise through Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I have a `Rails 4` project where need to `setup SSL certificates` but sub-domain wise.

Actually, in my project users can create account with subdomain then users can setup own SSL certificates which will be use them subdomain site.

```
Like: xyz.mainsite.com, abc.mainsite.com
```

As per above example xyz.mainsite.com can use them own SSL certificates and same way for abc.

Any one have idea, how to manage or handle it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilites for this based on the web server you are using.

For example, if you are using Nginx, you can try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/729408/how-to-configure-ssl-for-a-subdomain-on-nginx)

If you are using Apache web server, you can try [this](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)

If you want to dynamically configure the SSL certificate at user action, then you can to write shell script to modify the file contents and call the shell script from your Rails code.

Comment: Thanks @Jay for answers here. Do you have any experience or how to call Shell scripts from Rails. Any idea then share which will be more use for me.

Comment: Modifying the file contents can be possible in many ways. Like you can do it in shell script or ruby script, etc. You can try ruby script if you are comfortable. Since you asked about calling shell script from Rails - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299231/execute-shell-script-from-ruby-on-rails-with-passing-variable